# Bash Trap Handler Race Condition

Tags: bash, trap

I am playing with bash's trap feature. And the following script exhbits some kind of race condition.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
set -x

trap sigusr1 USR1
ANCESTOR_PID=$$

function sigusr1
{
    num+=1
    declare -p num
}

function have_a_child
{
    sleep $(echo $((1 + RANDOM % 500)) / 1000 | bc -l) &
    wait $!
    kill -USR1 $ANCESTOR_PID
}

declare -i i=0
declare -i num=0

while (( i < 100 )); do
    have_a_child &
    i+=1
done

mkfifo -m 0400 /tmp/test.sh.fifo
read < /tmp/test.sh.fifo
```

Simply put, I create 100 child processes, which sleep randomly for 0 ~ 500 ms and then each one send a USR1 single to its parent. When their parent recives USR1 singal, it will increment **num** variable by 1.

**IF** **no race condition** happened, and every USR1 signal sent by every child process is processed by the parent script **sequentially**, the **num** variable shoud be **100** when all child process terminates. But I observe that **num** is random, something like **98, 93, 96** ...

So, I guess some nesting or function re-entry happend here: When the trap handler is processing one USR1 signal sent from some child, another USR1 singnal is sent by aother child, and maybe a third child process can be involed likewise...

Questions:

1. I am not sure when multiple sigles are received by the parent, whether the parent spawns multiple handlers like multiple threads or the parent just do some nesting process logic?
2. Is there any mechanism in bash can be used to work around this race condition?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8653845/10765659) maybe?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That seems right. Since one process can have at most one pending signal of the same type, some USR1 signals may just well be dropped! I’ll do more test to verify this. Thanks very much!